# Pass arguments from Tcl script to cygwin bash

Tags: bash, shell, tcl

i need to call cygwin bash from a tcl script and execute some arguments just after the bash is opened.
here's my code :

```
set gitBash ""

append gitBash "C:/cygwin/bin"

cd $gitBash

set command exec

lappend command "bash.exe"

lappend command "-c"

lappend command "cd cygdrive/c/workset"
```

The problem is i get this error

```
couldn't execute "exec bash.exe -c {cd cygdrive\c\workset\CASTLE5\2_Castle5_Dev\1_Castle}": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec $command"
```

any hints ?

Comment: Your fundamental problem here is that you're (attempting to) launch a shell, change directory within the shell, and then the shell exits. This smells like an XY problem: what is your actual goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) does not accept all arguments as one single *string*. The safest way to construct a shell command is to use a [`list`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm):

```
% set command [list bash -c "cd /some/dir"]
bash -c {cd /some/dir}
% eval exec $command
bash: line 0: cd: /some/dir: No such file or directory
% exec {*}$command
bash: line 0: cd: /some/dir: No such file or directory
%
```

Note that the [`{*}`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) syntax requires Tcl 8.5.

Comment: Many thanks , now i do not see the error but , the Cygwin bash doesn't appear . it's like nothing happened

Comment: @IbrahimShazly It ran very quickly and then disappeared again (as `cd` is a very quick command to execute and one that you won't see the result of without doing other commands after it; the parent process _does not_ see the child's `cd`). The window simply didn't have time to show up and for your eyes/brain to register it before it was gone again.